# Suppressing output when defining a function that opens a notebook

Tags: notebooks, output

I have a command to open a new notebook and generate a reference table. It is basically this with 2+2 replaced by a large table command:

```
NotebookEvaluate[
  CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[2 + 2], "Input"]], 
  InsertResults -> True];
```

When I execute the above, it does exactly what it is supposed to do. Next, I want to make it into a function that my students can call when needed:

```
func[___]:=NotebookEvaluate[
  CreateDocument[ExpressionCell[Defer[2 + 2], "Input"]], 
  InsertResults -> True];
```

When I execute `func[]` it creates the notebook as required but also executes the ExpressionCell inside the current notebook, apparently ignoring the ; to suppress the output. I have no idea why it is doing that or how to stop it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a precedence issue, fixed by using parentheses. Use `func[___] := (NotebookEvaluate[..];) instead.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks @CarlWoll. That did it.